# Python encode() vs JSON.stringify() before sending data over the network?

Tags: javascript, python, string, unicode, encoding

In Python, when sending a `POST` request to an API endpoint, we need to `encode()` the data, that encodes it using **UTF-8** and bytes type is assigned to the resulting Object. Why exactly do we need to encode it before sending?

What if we send it without encoding it? **What would happen if we send it as a Unicode string instead of converting it to UTF-8?**

In JavaScript, we do something similar like `JSON.stringify()`. Does this serve the same purpose as `encode()`? Why exactly do we need to use `stringify()` in a `POST` request?

I know the overall working of character encodings, but I cannot find any article that explains it deeply as to why exactly we use `JSON.stringify()`/`JSON.parse()` in JS and `encode()`/`decode()` in Python. Can we not send data without using these functions? Can anyone explain by comparing these four functions?

Comment: Regarding Python a string is a sequence of characters. To store or transmit a character there must be a defined representation of it as one or more bytes because only bytes can actually be stored or transmitted. This representation definition is the encoding/decoding.

Comment: You can't transmit objects, only bytes, so objects have to be *serialized* into a transmittable format, and then *deserialized* on the other end to reconstruct the objects.